# How to use LogisticRegressionWIthLBFGS with a Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I wouldlike to use the MLLIB LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS in a program designed to use ML algorithms and Dataframes.
Is there a simple way to convert my dataframe into an RDD without writing a new program again ?
Something like this doesn't work :

```
df3.cache()
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().run(df3.rdd)
val predictions = model.transform(df3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map your df3.rdd[Row] to a RDD[LabeledPoint]

So it depends on your schema and all.